# cannot press continue when installing latest ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

During the installation procedure there are some windows where the continue button at the lower right corner is outside the window. Knowing this one can press tab several times to come there, but you are lost when you don't know it. There is also no possibility to scroll or to enlarge the window.

Comment: I've never encountered this during install (14.04, 16.04, 20,04, 22,04).  What version were you installing?

Comment: This sounds like you’re installing Elementary in a VirtualBox instance rather than Ubuntu. Could you elaborate on the type of system you’re installing the OS onto as well as which version of Ubuntu is being used?

Answer (score 2):

You can always press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag the window with your mouse.

It is helpful in your case.